# Copy pandas dataframe to excel using openpyxl

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, clipboard, openpyxl

I have some complicated formating saved in a template file into which I need to save data from a pandas dataframe. Problem is when I use pd.to_excel to save to this worksheet, pandas overwrites the formatting. Is there a way to somehow 'paste values' form the df into the worksheet? I am using pandas 0.17

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
wb= openpyxl.load_workbook('H:/template.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('spam')
sheet.title = 'df data'
wb.save('H:/df_out.xlsx')

xlr = pd.ExcelWriter('df_out.xlsx')
df.to_excel(xlr, 'df data')
xlr.save()
```

Answer (score 41):

openpyxl 2.4 comes with a utility for converting Pandas Dataframes into something that openpyxl can work with directly. Code would look a bit like this:

```
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
rows = dataframe_to_rows(df)

for r_idx, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
    for c_idx, value in enumerate(row, 1):
         ws.cell(row=r_idx, column=c_idx, value=value)
```

You can adjust the start of the enumeration to place the cells where you need them.

See [openpyxl documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/2.4/pandas.html) for more information.

Comment: May be we shall have a function like DataFrame to sheet?

Comment: @Abbas I don't think that is necessary at all. Once 2.4 is released I will work with Pandas to make use of this in the `df.to_excel()` method.

Comment: Will this allow me to choose a different row from df to an arbitrary row in the file and repeat it for all rows ?

Comment: This is the long lost answer to how to overwrite the data of an existing sheet using pandas and openpyxl! I added: rows = dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=True)

Comment: @CharlieClark  *I don't think that is necessary at all. Once 2.4 is released I will work with Pandas to make use of this in the df.to_excel() method.*  => Any progress on the support of `openpyxl.Workbook` in `df_to_excel`?

Answer (score 13):

I slightly modified @CharlieClark's great answer to avoid the index (which is not there in the original Excel file). Here is a ready-to-run code:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx')  # load as openpyxl workbook; useful to keep the original layout
                                 # which is discarded in the following dataframe
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')  # load as dataframe (modifications will be easier with pandas API!)
ws = wb.active
df.iloc[1, 1] = 'hello world'    # modify a few things
rows = dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False)
for r_idx, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
    for c_idx, value in enumerate(row, 1):
        ws.cell(row=r_idx, column=c_idx, value=value)
wb.save('test2.xlsx')
```

Comment: dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=True) if you've headers

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for you using [`clipboard`](https://github.com/terryyin/clipboard):

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import clipboard as clp

#Copy dataframe to clipboard
df.to_clipboard()
#paste the clipboard to a valirable
cells = clp.paste()
#split text in varialble as rows and columns
cells = [x.split() for x in cells.split('\n')]

#Open the work book
wb= openpyxl.load_workbook('H:/template.xlsx')
#Get the Sheet
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('spam')
sheet.title = 'df data'
#Paste clipboard values to the sheet
for i, r in zip(range(1,len(cells)), cells):
    for j, c in zip(range(1,len(r)), r):
        sheet.cell(row = i, column = j).value = c
#Save the workbook
wb.save('H:/df_out.xlsx')
```

Comment: This creates two intermediate data structures: the clipboard and cells.

Comment: I was looking for something like paste clipboard in `openpyxl`, similar to the functions in `pandas`.

Comment: There will be the `ws.values` property which we will be an easy way to get at the values of a worksheet but this will not be writable. `ws.iter_cols()` will provide an columnar interface for editable worksheets.

Answer (score 1):

I extended and Charlie's answer and extracted it into a function which imitates the signature of [`DataFrame.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

```py
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

def df_to_excel(df, ws, header=True, index=True, startrow=0, startcol=0):
    """Write DataFrame df to openpyxl worksheet ws"""

    rows = dataframe_to_rows(df, header=header, index=index)

    for r_idx, row in enumerate(rows, startrow + 1):
        for c_idx, value in enumerate(row, startcol + 1):
             ws.cell(row=r_idx, column=c_idx).value = value
```

Example use, note that `openpyxl` puts the index name on a *second line* below the actual index, which is different behavior compared to `DataFrame.to_excel`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import os

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=["A", "B"]).rename_axis("Index")
df_to_excel(df, wb.active)
wb.save("out.xlsx")
os.startfile("out.xlsx")  # open the file in Excel (only works on Windows)
```

Answer (score 0):

you shoud to get your data shap first to determine the range of loop

```
wb_formats=load_workbook("template.xlsx")            
ws_index=wb_formats.get_sheet_by_name("index")
daily_input= pd.read_excel(self.readfile,"input")
list_item=data_analysis1.groupby(["item_id"])["product_name"].unique()
list_item_size=pd.DataFrame(list_item,columns=["product_name"]).shape[0]

#create  the index sheet:
            r = 2  # start at 4th row
            c = 1 # column 'a'
            for row in range(0,list_item_size):  
                rows = list_item.iloc[row]
                for item in rows:
                    ws_index.cell(row=r, column=c).value = item
                    c += 1 # Column 'd'
                c = 1
                r += 1
wb_formats.save(save_name)
```