# How to insert tables from python in Excel

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to insert values stored in a table in Python (values from tables in tables to be more precise) into an Excel-file. I know how to store one value in one cell using openpyxl, however, I fail to find any resource on how to assign values from tables in Python to a range of cells in Excel.

I haven't tried anything yet since I'm a complete beginner with Python. My guess would be to grab each value within the table with a loop and insert these values in Excel. Altough I thought openpyxl had a certain function to do so.

It would be appreciated if you gave me a small piece of code as a starting point.

e.g:

```
row1 = [5, 10]
row2 = [4, 9]
table = [row1, row2]
```

How would you proceed to store the values from the tables row1 in row 1, columns A and B and the values from row2 in row 2 and columns A and B?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Excel can open CSVs, so you can output that if it's an option for you.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried searching online ? There must have been someone with this issue. Your guess is correct, you either have to loop all fields row by row and print them to excel, **or** you can load the data in a `pandas` dataframe and use the `df.to_excel()` function. I suggest the former since dataframes can be unnecessarily complicated for this use case.

Comment: You can find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36657288/copy-pandas-dataframe-to-excel-using-openpyxl

Comment: `ws.append(row1)`