# python xlsxwriter export dataframe and plotly graphs to different tabs in one excel

Tags: python, graph, export, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to export some dataframes and plotly graphs to different tabs in one excel. Each tab shall contain only one dataframe or graph. I had the dataframe export part done but I don't know how to export the plotly graphs using similar logic.

**Xlsxwriter: exporting two dataframes: table and misc_user**

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path_output + '\Report_{}.xlsx'.format(*arg), engine='xlsxwriter')

table.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Uploads')
misc_user.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Misc Users')

writer.save()
```

I then have two plotly graphs made from two other dataframes

```
# plotly 
user_evt_long = px.line(user_evt_long, x='Month', y='Times', color='ELEVATE?')

# Show plot 
user_evt_long.show()
```

```
top_users_fig = px.bar(top_users, x='account_name', y='users_count', title = 'Top Ten Uploads')

top_users_fig.show()
```

So there shall be four tabs in total. 'Uploads' tab contains `table`, 'Misc users' tab contains `misc_user`, 'Users' tab contains `user_evt_long`, and 'Top Users' contains `top_users_fig`.

How can I export `user_evt_long` and `top_users_fig` using similar logic as the dataframe export?

Comment: You want 2 plots in different tabs right? or you want your dataframe also in different tabs? so total 4 tabs you are looking for? or something like one dataframe with figure in 1 tab and other dataframe with other fig in other tab?

Comment: I would like each tab to contain only one dataframe or graph. So there shall be four tabs in total. 'Uploads' tab contains 'table' dataframe, 'Misc users' tab contains 'misc_user' dataframe, 'Users' tab contains 'user_evt_long' graph, and 'Top Users' contains 'top_users_fig' graph. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example of adding a Plotly image to the same worksheet as the Pandas dataframe and also to a new worksheet.

```py
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO


# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_plotly.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Make a plotly chart.
fig = px.bar(df)

# Convert it to a BytesIO stream.
image_data = BytesIO(fig.to_image(format="png"))

# Write the image to the same sheet as the data.
worksheet.insert_image(2, 3, 'plotly.png', {'image_data': image_data})

# Create a new worksheet and add the image to it.
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.insert_image(2, 3, 'plotly.png', {'image_data': image_data})

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

**Output**:

[image]

Note, it is also possible to plot charts from Pandas dataframes directly in Xlsxwriter. See the [Adding Charts to Dataframe output](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#adding-charts-to-dataframe-output) section of the XlsxWriter docs.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the snippet. You can use `openpyxl` to insert image and dataframe to separate tabs. Each time you would need to mention tab name you are creating.

This is just a sample example which i created . You can modify it as per your requirement. But it creates 4 tags as you require.

You would need to first save your image using `fig.write_image` then only you would be able to insert it.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly
import pandas as pd

data = [['Ravi',21,67],['Kiran',24,61],['Anita',18,46],['Smita',20,78],['Sunil',17,90]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns = ['name','age','marks'],dtype = float)
trace = go.Bar(x = df.name, y = df.marks)
fig = go.Figure(data = [trace])
fig.write_image("Plotly1.png")

wb = Workbook()
sheet1 = wb.create_sheet('image1',0)
active = wb['image1']
active.add_image(Image('Plotly1.png'),'A1')

sheet2 = wb.create_sheet('image2',0)
active1 = wb['image2']
active1.add_image(Image('Plotly1.png'),'A1')

sheet3 = wb.create_sheet('marks',0)
active2 = wb['marks']
rows = dataframe_to_rows(df)

for r_idx, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
    for c_idx, value in enumerate(row, 1):
         active2.cell(row=r_idx, column=c_idx, value=value)

sheet4 = wb.create_sheet('marks1',0)
active3 = wb['marks1']
rows1 = dataframe_to_rows(df)
for r_idx, row in enumerate(rows1, 1):
    for c_idx, value in enumerate(row, 1):
         active3.cell(row=r_idx, column=c_idx, value=value)
wb.save('new.xlsx')
```

You can refer [static-image-export](https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/) as well as
[df.to_excel using openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36664027/12870513) for more details