# Pasting a dataframe into excel using openpyxl

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, automation, openpyxl

I have a table which is the output of a sql query and I want this table to be pasted into a specific cell of an excel (say B10).Using openpyxl I used to do
`ws_hi["c31"].value = output_total.iloc[0]`
(*ws_hi is the excel sheet and output_total is the variable which holds the data I wanna copy*)
which works fine for a single value but not for a table. Need help in exporting if output_total is a 4*5 table

FYI output_total is dataframe obtained by
`output_total = pd.read_sql_query(text(query), engine1)`
thanks!

Comment: so you want to copy a entire table to xlsx cell?

Comment: No, I want the table as is for example a 2*2 output would be pasted like value(1,1) in cell b10 , value(1,2) in cell c10 value(2,1) in b11 and so on

Comment: Look at openpyxl.utils.dataframe

Comment: Thank you for you response, Charlie. I am an absolute beginner, Could you please elaborate on something specific? maybe with an example?

Comment: have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36664027/14333932

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is stored in a pandas DataFrame, you can use [`pd.DataFrame.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) and specify the upper left cell where you want to dump your data with `startrow` and `startcol`.

In your case this would be something like the following for the B10 cell:

```py
output_total.to_excel('excel/file/path.xlsx', startrow=11, startcol=1, header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: Maybe I had to mention, the excel I had to write into had other data. to_excel just deleted all the prior data I had saved there