# append pandas dataframe to existing excel file with start at specific cell

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

If I have a dataframe

```
   0    1     2
0  0.1  0.2   0.3
1  0.2  0.3   0.4
2  0.3  0.4   0.5
3  0.4  0.5   0.6
```

and I want to append it to my existing excel file, I will then write code

```
wb = load_workbook('test1.xlsx')

ws = wb['Sheet1']

for index, row in newdf.iterrows():
    cell = 'D%d'  % (index + 2)
    ws[cell] = row[0]

wb.save('test1.xlsx')
```

The problem with that code is, I only get the first column, since its iterating over the index. So for example this is excel sheet.

```
A B C D
1
2     0.1
3     0.2
4     0.3
5     0.4
```

How to make iteration until all the column finish with start at D2 cell ? I ve tried iteritems also it did not work.

```
expected result should be 
A B C D   E    F
1
2     0.1 0.2  0.3
3     0.2 0.3  0.4
4     0.3 0.4  0.5
5     0.4 0.5  0.6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proposition based on your code :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

wb = load_workbook("test1.xlsx")
ws = wb["Sheet1"]

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    for j, value in enumerate(row):
        r, c = i + 2, get_column_letter(j + 4)
        cell_coordinates = f"{c}{r}"
        ws[cell_coordinates] = value

wb.save("test1.xlsx")
```

There is also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36664027/16120011) from @*Charlie Clark* that you can adapt to your needs.

Output :

[image]